# Sortablejs - sortablejs_1.MultiDrag is not a constructor in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, angular-sortablejs

I am using ngx-sortable library and it's my first contact with it. According to documentation I've included the line below to have MultiDrag.

```
Sortable.mount(new MultiDrag(), new Swap());
```

Component works fine.
But when I try to run my unit tests it fails with an error:

> TypeError: sortablejs_1.MultiDrag is not a constructor

SortablejsModule was imported in the spec file. I spent some time on searching the internet but I couldn't find the solution. Do you know what is the reason of that error?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I have same problem, did you find an answer?